What is the AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo preset for iPhone 14/15 Pro/Max 48MP main camera?
My iOS app for iPhone configures a capture session with the .builtInWideAngleCamera and AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo. Most modern iPhones have a 12MP main camera, however, the iPhone 14 Pro and 15 Pro models now have 48MP main cameras. What resolution and aspect ratio can I expect from the .photo preset for these newer Pro models?
I only have iPhones as new as the 13 Pro to test with, and simulators are useless to check this type of thing.
Additionally, is resolution and aspect ratio the only 2 metrics differentiating the .photo preset and, say, .hd4k4032x3024? Or are settings like zoom, exposure, white balance, etc. also possibly different amongst the presets?

You can check how to capture 48MP ProRAW here.
As I know firstly the 48MP ProRAW capture is only available when you set the the preset to photo, and set the quality other than speed .
The photo preset can not enable stabilization when compared with other video presets.
Btw, the zoom is only available using ProRAW, if you using the ByerRAW, the app will crash.

Thanks for that link. It seems that unless specifically configured to capture ProRAW 48MP, the resulting image will be 12MP.
